# UIWebView pich to zoom work on iPhone 5.0 simulator but not work in iPhone 4.3 and iPad 4.3, 5.0 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview, zooming

I write a custom ViewController have a webview like below:

```
@interface WebpageController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView* webView;
//....
}
```

and it constructor:

```
-(id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
    webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    webView.delegate=self;
        webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
//.....
}
```

and I have 3 function to zoomin, zoom out and loadHTMLString to webView below:

```
//this is load HTML String function
// param: content --> HTML conten by inside <body> </body>
 -(void) loadWebViewWithContent:(NSString*) content{

    NSString * header = @"<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable= yes;'/>";

    NSString * html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> 
                                                      <head>%@ </head> 
                                                      <body> %@ </body>
                                                   </html>",header,content];
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

}
```

//these are zoom in and zoom out function

```
-(void) zoomIn {
    for (UIScrollView *scroll in [self.webView subviews]) {
        //Set the zoom level.
        if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:animated:)]) {
            NSLog(@"set ZoomScale work");

            [scroll setZoomScale:2.0f animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"zoomScale of SCROLLVIEW= %f",(scroll.zoomScale));

        }
    }

}
-(void) zoomOut {

    for (UIScrollView *scroll in [self.webView subviews]) {
        //Set the zoom level.

        if ([scroll respondsToSelector:@selector(setZoomScale:animated:)]) {

            NSLog(@"set ZoomScale work");
            [scroll setZoomScale:0.5f animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"zoomScale of SCROLLVIEW= %f",(scroll.zoomScale));

        }

    }

}
```

In main UI, I set that when user tap on ZoomIn button --> webView zoomIn by call zoomIn function (the same for zoomOut)

Everything is OK when I test on iPhone 5.0 simulator (I use xCode 4.2).You can pinch to zoomin, zoomOut ( also use zoomIn, zoomOut button).
But when test on Iphone 4.3 and IPad (both 4.3 and 5.0) ---> no thing happen --> the LOG show that :

****set ZoomScale work**

**zoomScale of SCROLLVIEW= 1.00;**
 ***---> also I set another value but zoomScale always = 1.00 --> no change*****

What is wrong with my code?? I'm so confused.Please help me.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

this is for scrollview zooming method..

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    return contentView;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrllView 
{
    CGRect rectZoom = [self centeredFrameForScrollView:scrllView andUIView:contentView]; 
    contentView.frame = rectZoom; //[self centeredFrameForScrollView:scrllView andUIView:contentView];
}

-(CGRect)centeredFrameForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scroll andUIView:(UIView *)rView 
{
    CGSize boundsSize = scroll.bounds.size;
    CGRect frameToCenter = rView.frame;

    // center horizontally
    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width) 
    {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    }
    else 
    {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;
    }

    // center vertically
    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height) 
    {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    }
    else 
    {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;
    }
    frameToCenter = CGRectMake(frameToCenter.origin.x, frameToCenter.origin.y, frameToCenter.size.width, frameToCenter.size.height);
    return frameToCenter;
}
```

if not working let know...

Answer (score 0):

Better you use always the self."iVar name".

```
@interface WebpageController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webview;
@end
@implementation
  @synthesize webView;
@end
```

and later refer to it like self.webView.